# Can I do a not in except for in my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Not sure if this is possible but I am trying to select all values from a table excluding records with a specific value in a field, but not if another field has a specific value.

For Example My Table:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Status | Flag
```

Data:

```
FOO | BAR | Working On | 0
FOO | BAR | Working On | 0
FOO | BAR | Working On | 0
FOO | BAR | Complete   | 0
FOO | BAR | Complete   | 1
FOO | BAR | Complete   | 1
```

I would Like to return all the records that are not status = complete unless the flag = 0. So I would get something like this returned:

```
FOO | BAR | Working On | 0
FOO | BAR | Working On | 0
FOO | BAR | Working On | 0
FOO | BAR | Complete   | 0
```

My Current Query

```
SELECT * FROM table where status NOT IN ('COMPLETE')
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? The [tag:mysql] tag is not meant for "my SQL problem"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE flag = 0 OR status <> 'Complete'
```

Comment: Thank's my actual sql is so complex now I overlooked the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
select *
from table
where status not in ('Complete')
or    flag = 0
```

Comment: Sorry that is just because I was re typing. Cases do match but that will exclude all records with status complete. I need to include records with status complete and flag = 0

Comment: Don't use `UPPER()` - use a case insensitive collation!

Comment: I wasn't aware of that possibility in MySQL.